# No tests found. Cypress could not detect tests in this file

Tags: testing, cucumber, cypress, integration-testing, cucumberjs

I am working with Cypress and the cucumber plugin. When I try to run Cypress I keep getting

```
No tests found. 
Cypress could not detect tests in this file
```

I am referencing another question regarding this error, but it was going into a missing a spec file which is not the problem here. I've imported the correct step definitions as per docs but it's not pointing to that either.

For now here is my file structure.

```
cypress -
    -integrations
        -BDD
           -ecommerce
              -ecommerce.spec.js
           - ecommerce.feature
```

In my cypress.json file

```
    "testFiles":  "**/*.js",
    "baseUrl": "https://localhost:17843/GfmAdminConsole/",
    "env":{
        "url":"https://rahulshettyacademy.com"
    },
    "reporter": "mochawesome"
    
}
```

and here is the code I am trying to run

```
import {Given,When,Then,And} from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps'
import HomePage from "./HomePage"
import ProductPage from "./ProductPage"
import CheckOutPg from "./CheckOutPg"







/// <reference types="Cypress" />
Given('I open ECommerce Page',()=>{
    cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
})


//When using hook to load data, use non-es6 syntax for a function.....might need to check if this was updated in later releases
When('I add items to Cart',function(){
    const homePage = new HomePage()
    const productPage = new ProductPage()
    homePage.getShopTab().click()
    
    
    testData.productName.forEach((product)=>{
        cy.selectProduct(product)
    })


    
    productPage.getCheckoutBtn().click()


})

And('Validate the total price of the items selected',()=>{
    let sum = 0
    let total;
    const checkOut = new CheckOutPg()
    checkOut.getItemPrices().each(($el,index,$list)=>{
        let price = $el.text().split(' ')[1].trim()
        sum = Number(sum) + Number(price);
    }).then(()=>{
        cy.log(sum)
        
    })
    checkOut.getTotal().then((el)=> {
        total =   el.text().split(' ')[1].trim()
        expect(Number(total)).to.eq(sum)
       })

})

Then('Select the country submit and verify Thank you',()=>{
    cy.get(':nth-child(6) > :nth-child(5) > .btn').click()
    cy.get('#country').type('United States')
    cy.wait(6000)
    cy.get('.suggestions > ul > li > a').click()
    cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').check({force:true})
    cy.get('.ng-untouched > .btn').click()
    cy.get('.alert').then((el)=>{
        const text = el.text()
       expect(text.includes('Success')).to.be.true
    })
})
```

EDIT:
ecommerce.feature file

```
Feature: End to end Ecommerce validation


application Regression test
@focus
Scenario: Ecommerce products delivery

Given I open ecommerce page
When I add items to cart
And Validate the total prices
Then select the country submit and verify Thankyou
```

Any guidance would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `cypress.json` according to https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#cypress-configuration there should be

```
"testFiles": "**/*.feature"
```

Answer (score 0):

> No tests found.
> Cypress could not detect tests in this file

I also got this error. I did 2 things to resolve it.

1. I added `"testFiles": "**/*.feature"` to my `cypress.json` file, just like @lojza mentioned in their answer. Thanks, @lojza!
2. I added a Scenario to my `.feature` file. Now my `.feature` file has this structure:

```
Feature: My awesome feature
    Background: Background name: Login to my awesome site
        Given I login to my awesome site
    Scenario: Add cool stuff. Then logout.
        Then I logout
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Cypress only need `specPattern` in the `cypress.config.ts`.

```
// cypress.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: './src/features/**/*feature'
  }
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration